# How to display information from table B where a field in Table A, has a number e.g 2345678 in a colum. i want all colum with this number appear only

Tags: php, mysql

I have Table 'A' which has ID, Name, gender, account_number. And table B has ID, Name, gender, account_number and more. Table B stores all information about different account users and numbers. i want if a row in Table A with account_number e.g 123456 matches in a row Table B with the same account_number then print all the information in Table B.

i tried doing this but it is not working properly.........

```
<? php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM trans INNER JOIN reg ON reg.Accnumber = trans.Transfer_id ");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td height="38"><?php echo $row['re_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bank_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['re_number']; ?></td>
        <td>$<?php echo $row['re_amount']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['swift_code']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['t_date']; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
          <?php
```

Please i need help

Comment: With `INNER JOIN`, you will have only list of A who have at least one match with B. Try with a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Camille "i want if a row in Table A with account_number e.g 123456 matches in a row Table B with the same account_number then print all the information in Table B." this sounds more like a INNER JOIN problem to me and not a LEFT JOIN

Comment: I think you need to use `SELECT tableB.* FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB USING(account_number) WHERE account_number = '123456'`  but iam not sure because your question is a bit unclear... with unclear i mean no example tables, example data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You mean left join? 
to select all values from table A and then to get data from table B only if it is in table A?

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b USING(account_number)
```

Pay attention, that 1st table should be that one that have less data.
If you have small transaction list and you want to get Account's holders details for it, it would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM trans 
LEFT JOIN reg ON reg.accnumber = trans.accnumber
WHERE reg.accnumber = '123456'
```

And if you have customer's list and want to find transactions for them:

```
SELECT reg.*, group_concat(trans.transfer_id)
FROM reg 
LEFT JOIN trans USING (accnumber)
GROUP BY reg.accnumber
```

And you can filter that data, but you probably need to use Having instead of Where if you have more than 1 transaction for your customer:

```
SELECT reg.*, count(trans.transfer_id) as qty
FROM reg 
LEFT JOIN trans ON reg.accnumber = trans.accnumber 
GROUP BY reg.accnumber
HAVING reg.accnumber = '123456'
```

if you need only transactions, you can request it from one table:

```
SELECT * FROM trans WHERE accnumber = '123456'
```

And if your tables are normalized, you should not have accnumber field in your trans table, the only foreign key to reg.id, then your query would be:

```
SELECT trans.*
FROM trans 
LEFT JOIN reg ON reg.id = trans.user_id
WHERE reg.accnumber = '123456'
```

Comment: What i mean is that Table A which is 'reg' contains all registered users with their account number and table B contain all transfer transaction of all Users. then if user login the he or she will see all this transaction without seeing other peoples transaction. so i used column name 'Accnumber' for account number in 'reg' Table which is A and table B column name 'transfer_id' which is table 'trans'

Comment: in such case it's usually is enough to request only table trans filtering it by Accnumber
SELECT * FROM trans WHERE accnumber = '123456'

Comment: Table A which is reg

Comment: you can provide exact tables and field names so I can write query